# SSIS package accepts password to open package but not to save

Tags: vb.net, ssis, ssis-2017

I am having issues with my password for SSIS 2017. When I open the package, it asks for the password. I provide the correct one, and it opens up everything properly. When I try to save it, it asks for the password. I provide it the same one, but it doesn't like it.  I tried to roll back the changes in TFS, but it does the same thing. It doesn't like the password. Any thoughts?

I've tried searching around the web, but no luck.

ERROR:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Error loading '#######.dtsx' : Failed to remove package
>   protection with error 0xC0014037 "The package is encrypted with a
>   password. The password was not specified, or is not correct.". This
>   occurs in the CPackage::LoadFromXML method.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below Microsoft docs link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#ssdt-for-vs-2017-standalone-installer